# React. useState + setInterval. В чем причина такого поведения state в компоненте?

Tags: setinterval, react-hook

Пишу на **React**. У меня возникли проблемы с пониманием того, что происходит с состоянием компонента при использовании хука **useState** совместно с функцией **setInterval**. Нужного поведения я добился, но в осадке чувствую, что кое-чего недопонял.

**Что я пытаюсь реализовать:**
инкремент и декремент переменной хранимой в состоянии компонента при зажатии указателя на элементе DOM каждые (скажем 200, но это не важно)мс

У меня есть 3 варианта кода, 2 работают не так как задумано, а именно при зажатии "+" значение переменной меняется постоянно в 1 и тут же обратно в 0.
Ну и один рабочий вариант.

Я понял, что это можно реализовать при помощи хука useEffect, в принципе мне удалось и без него, но вопрос в другом, **почему 2 моих варианта ведут себя не так, как я ожидаю, а один из них все таки работает должным образом?**

К слову, работоспособность варианта №3, при условии неработоспособности варианта №2 меня очень сильно удивляет, так как всегда считал подобное равнозначным.

Нерабочий вариант №1:

```
const IndexPage = function () {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(null)
  const delay = 200

  function inc() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(setInterval(setCount, delay, count + 1))
  }

  function dec() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(setInterval(setCount, delay, count - 1))
  }

  function clean() {
    clearInterval(id)
  }
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <p style={btn} onPointerDown={inc} onPointerUp={clean}>
        +
      </p>
      <p style={btn} onPointerDown={dec} onPointerUp={clean}>
        -
      </p>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Нерабочий вариант №2 (только изменённые функции):

```
function inc() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(
      setInterval(setCount, delay, ++contextCount)
    )
  }

  function dec() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(
      setInterval(setCount, delay, --contextCount)
    )
  }
```

Рабочий вариант:

```
function inc() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(
      setInterval(() => {
        setCount(++contextCount)
      }, delay)
    )
  }

  function dec() {
    let contextCount = count
    setId(
      setInterval(() => {
        setCount(--contextCount)
      }, delay)
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В варианте: `setInterval(setCount, delay, ++contextCount)` `contextCount` увеличивается на 1 и создается замыкание для функции `setCount` которая будет вызвана с тем же значением.
Вот пример:

```js
const func = (count) => {
    console.log(`count`, count);
 };
 
let contextCount = 0;

const id = setInterval(func, 1000, ++contextCount);

setTimeout(() => clearInterval(id), 5000);
```

В последнем варианите у функции внутри `setInterval` есть доступ к внешней переменной, поэтому она может изменяться:

```js
let contextCount = 0;

const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`contextCount`, contextCount);
  ++contextCount;
}, 1000);
 
 setTimeout(() => clearInterval(id), 5000);
```